# match character not enclosed by braces recursively

Tags: regex, pcre

I'm trying to split a string on pipes, when they are not enclosed by braces.

i've got a regex that works, unless there are recursive braces:

```
~\([^)]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|\|~

test(test(test|tester)|test)|test
                      ^ and ^ are matched, only last one should match
```

[regex101 link to play around](https://regex101.com/r/FIqb8g/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following regex based on a subroutine:

```
(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))(*SKIP)(*F)|\|
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mG3vy8/1)

**Details**

- `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))` - Group 1 that matches

  - `\(` - a `(`
  - `(?:[^()]++|(?1))*` - 0 or more occurrences of:

    - `[^()]++` - any 1+ chars other than `(` and `)`
    - `|` - or
    - `(?1)` - the whole Group 1 pattern is recursed (note that `(?R)` would not work here since it would recurse the *whole* regex pattern)
  - `\)` - a `)` char
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - PCRE verb sequence that omits the currently matched text and makes the regex engine search for the next match beginning from the end of the current match
- `|` - or
- `\|` - a literal `|`